# SQL Server count of column not contained in aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, count

I am having quite the issue in creating the correct query for SQL Server. To start off, here is the data that I am trying to query.

```
TicketBookNum | TicketNum | Used | DateIssued | UnitID
---------------------------------------------
1234          |   25      |  Yes | Dec 18 2015 | 101
----------------------------------------------     
1234          |   26      |  Yes | Dec 18 2015 | 101
----------------------------------------------         
1234          |   27      |  Yes | Dec 18 2015 | 101
----------------------------------------------     
1234          |   28      |  No  | Dec 18 2015 | 101
----------------------------------------------     
1235          |   70      |  Yes | Dec 10 2015 | 102   
----------------------------------------------     
1235          |   71      |  Yes | Dec 10 2015 | 102    
----------------------------------------------        
1235          |   72      |  No  | Dec 10 2015 | 102    
----------------------------------------------       
1235          |   73      |  No  | Dec 10 2015 | 102   
----------------------------------------------
```

So am querying this data to put into a list view. TicketBookNum and TicketNum are the primary key combo. The query I am using to retrieve the data is a search function and it is this:

```
create procedure [dbo].[SearchTicketBooks]
@TicketBookNumber   nvarchar(10) = null,
@DateIssuedA        datetime = null,
@DateIssuedB        datetime = null,
@UnitID         nvarchar(10) = null
as
select distinct(TicketBookNum), DateIssued, U.UnitID, COUNT(Used) as 'Completed' --Error on this COUNT because there is no aggregate function
   from TicketBooks TB
    full outer join Units U
    on TB.UnitID=U.UnitID
where TicketBookNum = 
    (case when @TicketBookNumber is null or @TicketBookNumber = '' then TicketBookNum else @TicketBookNumber end)
and TB.UnitID = 
    (case when @UnitID is null or @UnitID = '' then TB.UnitID else @UnitID end)
and DateIssued = 
    (case when (@DateIssuedA is null and @DateIssuedB is null) or (@DateIssuedA = '' and @DateIssuedB = '') or 
     @DateIssuedB = @DateIssuedA or DateIssued between @DateIssuedA and @DateIssuedB then DateIssued else @DateIssuedA end)
order by DateIssued desc    
go
```

So what this query does is lets the user search for the Ticket Books by selecting a date range, the unit, or searching the direct ticketbook number. If nothing is selected in this search criteria, it returns all of the values.

I am trying to return the count for column Used where it equals Yes, and only for that Ticket book. So the desired result for no search criteria would be:

```
TicketBookNum | DateIssued | UnitID | Completed
-----------------------------------------------
1234          | Dec 18 2015| 101    |  3
1235          | Dec 10 2015| 102    |  2
```

I have been working on this for quite a while and I cannot figure it out. Hopefully I have supplied enough info, and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for your `Completed` column, and `GROUP BY` the other columns:

```
SUM(CASE Used WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed
```

Comment: Sorry, I am somewhat of a beginner in SQL. Would I need to group by all other columns, or just TicketBookNum? Wouldn't group by make the data not ordered by Date?

Comment: You would group by ALL the other columns in your select list (not all the columns in the table though).  You can still Order by Date or any of the other columns in the select list.   Oh and you can remove the DISTINCT from the select list, since Group By performs the same function.

Comment: Alright, I will give this a try. Thank you for your help!